# Number of processes

Tags: process, operating-system, fork

I am preparing for an exam, doing already solved exercises. However I have trouble with one concerning processes, because I think I do it right, however, the answer does not match mine. It is the following problem:

Below is the code for a program named Agent_Smith.c. Including the initial parent process, how many Agent_Smith processes are created? Assume there are no errors.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ejrb8.jpg

I know that only child processes have pid=0, while their parent inherits their actual pid (!=0). So I am doing this: (assuming smith = fork( ); is fork1 ect.)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/JrdEv.jpg

In the exercise it says that the processes *including* the initial parent are 12, but mine are 13 and I do not know where I do wrong. I think this is a mistake in the solution, however I am not sure so I wanted to ask. I am new to this website, so apologies if anything is done incorrectly.

Answer (score 0):

I also find 12 processes. I do not really understand your drawing, but here is what I find if all the forks are numbered 1-6 in program order. Processes are numbered as they would be created in program order.

```
P0 is parent
P0 -> fork1 P1  
P1 -> fork2 P2 
   -> fork3 P3
   -> fork4 P4
P2 -> fork3 P5 
   -> fork4 P6
P3 -> fork4 P7
P5 -> fork4 P8
P0 -> fork5 P9
   -> fork6 P10
P9 -> fork6 P11
```

So there 12 processes P0-P11.

By the way, never give a code as an image. There are ways to format them inline.

Answer (score 0):

Let us denote parent by `p0`.

So first fork() will generate a new child, so we will have 2 process till now.

Parent will get a value greater than 0. So it will enter in the for loop, next 2 `fork()` will generate 3 new process. So till now we have 1 parent and 4 new process.

Now first child process will execute the else statement. Three `fork()` will generate total 8 process including first child and 7 new process. In the end we will get 1 parent, 1 child generated in starting 3 new process generated in if condition, 7 new process generated in else condition. So total 12 processes.